# Annotate a class at compile-time if it belongs to a package

Tags: logging, groovy

I like the `@Log` family of annotations in [groovy.util.logging](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/util/logging/Log.html) and want to use them, but it's awfully tedious to have to remember to add that annotation to every class.

Is there a way to use Groovy's AST Transformation feature to do something like this:

- For every class within a given package (search recursively)
- If one of the `@Log` annotations does not exist
- Add the annotation (retention policy would have to be runtime)

The goal is to not have to manually put `@Log` in front of every class declaration within my package hierarchy so I can just use `log.info()` etc. from everywhere without thinking about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it by package, but you might want to look at Groovy's compilation customizers:
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/#compilation-customizers

Comment: From the Groovy Slack Channel:
https://groovy-community.slack.com/archives/C2NEFCM55/p1500995613782141
@shils added:
 a source aware customizer should do - http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/#_source_aware_customizer